# Offloading data files from Amazon Redshift to Amazon S3 in Parquet format

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I would like to unload data files from Amazon Redshift to Amazon S3 in Apache Parquet format inorder to query the files on S3 using Redshift Spectrum. I have explored every where but I couldn't find anything about how to offload the files from Amazon Redshift to S3 using Parquet format. Is this feature not supported yet or was I not able to find any documentation about it. Could somebody who has worked on it share some light on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Redshift Unload to Parquet file format is supported as of Dec 2019:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
FORMAT PARQUET
```

It is mentioned in [Redshift Features](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/features/?hp=r#data-lake-export)

and also updated in [Unload Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

with an example provided in the [Unload Examples Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html)

*Excerpt of the official documentation:*

The following example unloads the LINEITEM table in Parquet format, partitioned by the l_shipdate column.

```
unload ('select * from lineitem')
to 's3://mybucket/lineitem/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (l_shipdate);
```

Assuming four slices, the resulting Parquet files are dynamically partitioned into various folders.

```
s3://mybucket/lineitem/l_shipdate=1992-01-02/0000_part_00.parquet
                                             0001_part_00.parquet
                                             0002_part_00.parquet
                                             0003_part_00.parquet
s3://mybucket/lineitem/l_shipdate=1992-01-03/0000_part_00.parquet
                                             0001_part_00.parquet
                                             0002_part_00.parquet
                                             0003_part_00.parquet
s3://mybucket/lineitem/l_shipdate=1992-01-04/0000_part_00.parquet
                                             0001_part_00.parquet
                                             0002_part_00.parquet
                                             0003_part_00.parquet
```

Comment: Hi secdatabase, welcome to StackOverflow. Linking to external sites can be useful, but please include a quick summary of the important points from them in case the link breaks in the future.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but [Spectrify](https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify) does exactly this.

Comment: do you have any documentation on how to configure s3 paths and aws credentials for spectrify from python script?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Redshift doesn't know about Parquet (although you can read Parquet files through the Spectrum abstraction).

You can `UNLOAD` to text files. They can be [encrypted or zipped](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html), but they are only ever flat text files.

---

Looks like this is now supported:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-redshift-can-now-copy-from-parquet-and-orc-file-formats/

Comment: Just to clarify - the blogpost mentioned is about copying INTO Redshift, not out to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, so far, AWS Redshift did not extend its ability to read the parquet format.

Though you can do one of the following :

1. Use AWS Spectrum to read them.
2. Use a crawler from Amazon Glue to convert it for you.

Till today, there is no support for Apache Parquet in AWS out of the shelf.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about getting data out of Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution 'Spectrify' does this but if you don't want to do it using the AWS Services; you could use Spark on EMR + Databricks to read data from Redshift and write it into S3 in parquet format.

The following link will give you an idea to do the same

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-big-data-blog/tree/master/aws-blog-spark-parquet-conversion